# Папки и файлы созданные моим Android приложением

Tags: java, android, файлы

Есть ли такая возможность определить, что папка или файл были созданы моим приложением на Андроид платформе?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

*"что папка или файл были созданы моим приложением на Андроид платформе?"*

**Зависит от ситуации.**

**1.** Если вы сохраняете файлики на sdcard под файловой системой FAT то вы не сможете узнать что это **именно ваши** файлы. Файловая система FAT не поддерживает такую работу, а андроид не пишет кто создавал именно эти файлики.

**2.** Если вы используете апи по сохранению файлов во внутренню фс

(определенное место внутри data раздела, под управлением фс ext4)

то к вашим файлам и директориям никто не будет иметь доступа кроме вас. Причина в андроиде, приложения запускаются от уникальных пользователей, эти уникальные пользователи могут создавать файлы которые могут читать только они (линукс фс файлы все содержат индекс пользователя который их создал, а также права доступа).

Comment: Нужно создавать файлы с общим доступом.

Comment: Общего доступа? Все что пишется на sdcard считается по умолчанию общим:)

Comment: "то к вашим файлам и директориям никто не будет иметь доступа кроме вас"...

Answer (score 1):

1) Создайте файл, куда будете записывать путь своих созданных папок.

2) Делайте проверку: если путь проверяемой папки есть в файле => true

Comment: Неплохая идея, спасибо.